# Octave 4.2.2 having ambiguous issue while compiling with c++14

Tags: gcc, c++14, octave

Recently i upgraded to c++14 because of its advanced features, but i am facing ambiguous issue with Octave compilation for Range and Complex variables in my project where i used c++14 to compile ffmpeg,opencv,...etc.

with c++11 i never faced issue with octave 4.0.0 and 4.2.2 but only with c++14 i am facing issue.

It would be great help if someone provide solution to resolve this issue

```
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:173:26: error: reference to ‘Range’ is ambiguous
     idx_range_rep (const Range&);
                          ^
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:43:7: note: candidates are: class Range
 class Range;
       ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp:590:18: note:                 class cv::Range
 class CV_EXPORTS Range
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:206:5: error: reference to ‘Range’ is ambiguous
     Range unconvert (void) const;
     ^
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:43:7: note: candidates are: class Range
 class Range;
       ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp:590:18: note:                 class cv::Range
 class CV_EXPORTS Range
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:511:21: error: reference to ‘Range’ is ambiguous
   idx_vector (const Range& r)
                     ^
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:43:7: note: candidates are: class Range
 class Range;
       ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp:590:18: note:                 class cv::Range
 class CV_EXPORTS Range
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:1005:35: error: reference to ‘Range’ is ambiguous
                   double& scalar, Range& range,
                                   ^
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:43:7: note: candidates are: class Range
 class Range;
       ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp:590:18: note:                 class cv::Range
 class CV_EXPORTS Range
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/idx-vector.h:1005:35: error: ‘Range’ has not been declared
                   double& scalar, Range& range,
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/lo-utils.h:71:52: error: reference to ‘Complex’ is ambiguous
 extern OCTAVE_API bool xtoo_large_for_float (const Complex&  x);
                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/lo-utils.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct-cmplx.h:31:30: note: candidates are: typedef struct std::complex<double> Complex
 typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
                              ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:658:30: note:                 template<class _Tp> class cv::Complex
 template<typename _Tp> class Complex;
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/lo-utils.h:99:24: error: reference to ‘Complex’ is ambiguous
 template <> OCTAVE_API Complex octave_read_value (std::istream& is);
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/lo-utils.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct-cmplx.h:31:30: note: candidates are: typedef struct std::complex<double> Complex
 typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
                              ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:658:30: note:                 template<class _Tp> class cv::Complex
 template<typename _Tp> class Complex;
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/lo-utils.h:110:8: error: reference to ‘Complex’ is ambiguous
 inline Complex
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/lo-utils.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct-cmplx.h:31:30: note: candidates are: typedef struct std::complex<double> Complex
 typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
                              ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:658:30: note:                 template<class _Tp> class cv::Complex
 template<typename _Tp> class Complex;
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Array.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Sparse.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/oct.h:30,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.h:20,
                 from /home/arun/Desktop/proj/media/video.cpp:7:
/usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/lo-utils.h:132:47: error: reference to ‘Complex’ is ambiguous
 octave_write_complex (std::ostream& os, const Complex& cval);
                                               ^
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build oldstable? Can you try with GNU Octave 4.4.1 and/or 5.0.1?

Comment: hi Andy, I am using ubuntu 16.04 so i was using latest available in ppa repo

Comment: It is better to provide the source you have used. It seems that OpenCV and Octave have their own definitions of `Range` and `Complex`. If you want to use opencv types  use qualified names such as `cv::Range` and `cv::Complex` and dont use `using namespace cv;`.

Comment: I installed octave using the following commands                                          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave                                                                                                after installing i linked octave in cmakelists                                                                  in my cpp file i just add "octave/oct.h" along with opencv headers with this step itself i am getting the error

Comment: @Andy there's a 5.0.1 out??

Comment: hi rahnema1                                                                                                                                  you are correct after using cv:: issue is resolved thanks